# jQuery UI not styling in all the rows of HTML table

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, rows

I'm having a problem repeating the style done with jQuery UI when using a HTML table. All I want to do is create a table with various rows in it. Each row contains 2 columns. The first column will just be text. The second column will contain two jQuery UI buttons. I want to define a style and all the buttons in all the rows should change...but for some reason it does not. Only the first rows buttons gets styled.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <table cellpadding='10' align='center'>
        <tr style="display:block;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC !important;">
            <td width=400>Row 1</td>
            <td width=150>
                <button id="btnView" >View</button>
                <button id="btnCopy" >Copy</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display:block;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC !important;">
            <td width=400>Row 2</td>
            <td width=150>
                <button id="btnView" >View</button>
                <button id="btnCopy" >Copy</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display:block;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC !important;">
            <td width=400>Row 3</td>
            <td width=150>
                <button id="btnView" >View</button>
                <button id="btnCopy" >Copy</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#btnView").button({
        icons: {primary: "ui-icon-search"},text: false,label: "View"});
      $("#btnCopy").button({
        icons: {primary: "ui-icon-newwin"},text: false,label: "Copy"});
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is a fiddle for my code: http://jsfiddle.net/gtxc4/1/
Can anyone shed some light on why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't use an ID more than once in the same document. Change the IDs to classes (or just add classes) and adjust the jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $(".btnView").button({
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-search"
        },
        text: false,
        label: "View"
    });
    $(".btnCopy").button({
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-newwin"
        },
        text: false,
        label: "Copy"
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle with added classes: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/gtxc4/4/

Comment: It does the the job but you dont really need to use `.each()` just `$(".btnView").button({...` will suffice

Comment: Thank you for the comment Batu Zet - I removed `.each()` from the code.

Answer (score 0):

An id is supposed to be a unique identifier for an HTML tag element. To have CSS styles apply to more than one html element across your page use classes (as described in Niffler's answer). Classes allow you to apply one set of CSS styles to multiple html elements.